# Python, Appium, UIAutomator2 vs 1, Selenium - resourceID search not making sense

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

First post, please be kind.  I searched for more hours than I care to admit - desperate for an answer to a seemingly simple answer.

After a few hours, I was able to cross the bridge from `Selenium` to `Appium`, and get everything properly set up, and start automating directly to my attached `Moto G4 Play`.  Works with `the Appium` desktop perfect, and despite this being my first dive into Android internals, my initial tests with `Python/Appium` had me "auto-tapping" through the app quite nicely.

But, I ran into a brick wall because I simply cannot scroll the screen (in my script).  I figured that I needed to specify in `Appium` desired capabilities that I wanted to use `UIAutomator2`, since it has more scrolling options.  But, immediately, the `UIA2` engine couldn't find (by resourceID) the same element that could be found with `UIA1`.  I don't get it.  So, I decided to print every element that python script could detect on the page (with `UIA2`), and amongst those elements, it clearly showed the exact ResourceID that was found with `UIA1`.  At this point, I'm lost.  I can provide specifics, as requested, but hoping someone can start to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**  Additional info and code (thanks for the feedback data_garden).  Here's the line of code that fails going from `UIA1` to `UIA2`:

```
HeadMaster = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Head__master-id")))
```

A TimeoutException is thrown on `UIA2` (element not found):

The element is there, no doubt about that.  I not only listed it via my script, but inspected it with the `Appium` desktop and the `UIInspector`.

Is it perhaps related to some deprecated symbols?  Doubt it, considering underscores and dashes are pretty mainstream.

**EDIT:**

Also want to add this problem is occurring running `Appium Server 1.7.2`.

Comment: welcome to SO. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, on how to ask a question. in your case, displaying some code would help you to get your question answered.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post to be more specific.

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML

Comment: Hi.  What html are you referring to?  The android app source under Appium GUI inspector shows Appium Source line <android.view.View resource-id="Head__master-id"> in the App source tree.  Again both viewers see it, UIA1 finds it in the script, but UIA2 does not in the same exact script (except with automationName set to uiautomator2 in Appium's desired capabilities initialization).

Comment: Just wanted to be absolutely clear, the WebDriverWait throws a TimeoutException - not explicitly saying Element not found as I first stated.  Same result.  I updated original question for accuracy.

Comment: I figured a way around this bug (I think it's a bug), by using a different element.  I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to scroll using Appium and UIAutomator2 - nothing suggested works, and I've probably read hundreds of posts.  I've seen others express similar frustration.  There's even an appium method called scroll that takes two elements and it does absolutely NOTHING.  Ridiculously frustrating for such a basic step.  Argg.